# App submission, icon size error due to forthcoming IOS7 release

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios7

I submitted my app to Apple for the first time. The app is for iPad only and compiled for IOS6.
I got this reply from the submission process :

> Invalid Image - For iOS applications, icons included in the binary
>   submission must be in the PNG format
>
> If your application supports the iPhone device family, you must
>   include square icons of the following dimensions: 57x57 pixels and
>   120x120 pixels. If your application supports the iPad device family,
>   you must include square icons of the following dimensions: 72x72
>   pixels, 76x76 pixels and 152x152 pixels

[I read this morning that this is quite new](http://9to5mac.com/2013/08/30/apple-inadvertently-asking-developers-for-ios-7-optimized-app-icons/). I always have good chance when for my first attempts.

I only used png image files of 72x72, for exemple icon_72.png.
I understand that when I include a retina file, its name becomes icon_72@2x.png
But what about the other resolutions? 
How should I name them or how can I manage this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple mentioned in iOS 7 Human Interface Guidelines

> Create different sizes of the app icon for different devices. If
> you’re creating a universal app, you need to supply app icons in all
> four sizes.
>
> **For iPhone and iPod touch both of these sizes are required:**
>
> 120 x 120 pixels 60 x 60 pixels (standard resolution)
>
> **For iPad, both
> of these sizes are required:**
>
> 152 x 152 76 x 76 pixels (standard resolution)
>
> You can name these icons anything you want as long as you use the
> CFBundleIcons key to declare the names and you add the @2x suffix to
> the names of all high-resolution icons. **You can use custom names
> because iOS chooses an icon based on whether its size is appropriate
> for the intended usage.**

Comment: You do not need 60x60. That is a special case.

There are not any non-retina iPhones/iPods that will run iOS7, and you don't need this size for iOS6, so you only need the retina version for that icon, no matter what versions you support.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a photoshop user, you can download a template here: http://appicontemplate.com

There are photoshop actions included, that will automatically export all the formats you need.

To be on the safe side, use both the iOS 6 and iOS 7 template and include all the resolutions, you have been asked for.

Comment: thanks, I will take a look.
My image resources are mostly navigation bar icons.
To solve the issue, I think I will remove all these icons and only leave one. I hope to isolate the problem and the images involved.

Comment: The problem in this case really is your icon. Not the image resources inside your application. The exported images already have the right name. To be safe, just add all of them (except the high resolution iTunes images, that are for upload in iTunes Connect).

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify what I did (with some delay, sorry)

As mentioned I added 
icon76.png
icon76@2.png

and I modify the myapp-Info.plist adding the new icons in the "icon files" Array 
and it ended with :

- Item 0 icon72.png
- Item 1 icon72@2.png
- Item 2 icon76.png
- Item 3 icon76@2.png

I also had a small final issue with the png suffix that was capitalised : PNG

So thank you guys :  there's always good help here !

FKY